# Gradle sync fails when creating a new Kotlin project with default settings in freshly installed IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: kotlin, gradle, intellij-idea

I wanted to learn some Kotlin so I installed IntelliJ IDEA, created a new Kotlin project with the default settings and then the IDE tells me that Gradle sync has failed. Here's the error message:

```
Could not open init generic class cache for initialization script 'C:\Users\<my_name>\AppData\Local\Temp\wrapper_init.gradle' (C:\Users\<my_name>\.gradle\caches\6.8\scripts\344chmz69zyndatc9zp4rwux5).
> BUG! exception in phase 'semantic analysis' in source unit '_BuildScript_' Unsupported class file major version 60
```

I googled the error and got a suggestion to try a different JDK version. Tried a few different versions but that didn't help. Then I installed the IDE on my laptop to see if that works and there I don't get any errors. As far as I can tell, the project settings were exactly the same on both machines but obviously something is messed up on my desktop computer. Both have Windows 10.

I'm also not at all familiar with the Java/Kotlin ecosystem or the build tools or whatever so I honestly have no idea how I could even begin fixing some Gradle errors. I don't really even know what Gradle is or what it does. So can you help me?

Comment: Looks like https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-248808. Make sure you're not using JDK 16 anywhere (Project SDK, Gradle JDK).

Comment: You implement the plugins incorrectly like ```kt 
plugins { apply-plugins "vlah"}} ```

Answer (score 0):

First, check the version which the project uses: File > Project Structure. Or, during project creation (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXIzQ.png / [example with SDK 1.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trYqJ.png))

It has to be the same as JDK / SDK installed on your computer.

To verify java version installed in your terminal:

```
java -version

openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_252-8u252-b09-1~19.10-b09)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.252-b09, mixed mode)
```

Comment: I wish to help you more, but I think your error is relied to your Java environnement, and not the project itself.